# Error When Reading CSV With C Engine

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large data file that I'm trying to read into a Pandas Dataframe.

If I try to read it using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,
    sep='|',
    compression='gzip',
    skiprows=54,
    comment='#',
    names=column_names,
    header=None,
    usecols=column_numbers,
    engine='python',
    nrows=15347,
    na_values=["None", " "])
```

It works perfectly, but not quickly. If I try to use the `C engine` to speed the import up though, I get an error message:

```
 pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 0 fields in line 55, saw 205
```

It looks like something is going wrong when I change the engine, and the parser isn't figuring out how many\which columns it should be using. What I can't figure out is why. None of the input arguments are only supported by the Python engine.

The problem only occurred after I upgraded from version 14.1 to 16.0.

I can't attach a copy of the data, because it contains confidential information.

Comment: Cannot be responded without at least equivalent sample data.

Comment: Could you perhaps remove the confidential data and upload a dummy version of the data?

Comment: I'm trying to create a version of the data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Would line 55 be the exact line number in the source file? If so, would be really helpful sample from that region of the file.

Comment: It is, and I looked at that. Trying to reproduce the problem has made it look like the problem is actually to do with the file encoding.